# Launch Failed-execv in helper.app

Tags: macos, chromium-embedded

I have developed an MAC OS application(SampleApp) which uses CEFClient dylib(which I developed uses methods of CEF3 CEFClient). Now, when I launch my SampleApp I'm getting an error:
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/Users/macmini/Desktop/SampleApp/build/Debug/SampleApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/SampleAppHelper.app/Contents/MacOS/SampleApp Helper

I don't have an idea how to solve this issue. Can anyone please help me

Comment: SampleApp Helper exists?
Did you ask this question on ceforum?

Comment: Yes sampleapp helper exist. No I didn't ask this ques in cef forum